# How to create a random string of floats?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I want a function f(angleDeg), that takes an array of angles in degrees from 0

```
import numpy as np
import random

def f(angleDeg):
    angleRad = angleDeg*np.pi/180
    return angleRad
```

Now I create these random numbers:

```
x = [random.randint(5,85) for _ in range(50)]
x = [float(i) for i in x]
f(x)
```

However, I get the error:

> angleRad = angleDeg*np.pi/180
>   TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

I now fixed it using Garret Hyde's second method, and I'm trying to raise exceptions for numbers not in the range, so I have:

```
if not (angleDeg > 0).all():
   raise ValueError("angle must be between 0 and 90")
```

And it gives me the error:

> if not(angleDeg > 0).all():
>   AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: You probably want to make an `np.array` out of `x`, so that `*` means "element by element multiplication" rather than "sequence replication".  Whether the cast is best made at creation of `x`, or within `f`, depends on other details of your application/use case.

Comment: Do you want to raise an exception or just ignore invalid numbers by filtering them out?

Answer (score 1):

### Part 1

Your function is trying to multiply an array by pi. You need to either iterate over the array or use `numpy.array`.

```
def f(angleDeg):
    angleRad = [x * np.pi / 180 for x in angleDeg]
    return angleRad
```

Or

```
def f(angleDeg):
    angleRad = np.array(angleDeg) * np.pi / 180
    return angleRad
```

---

### Part 2

Again, you need to convert `angleDeg` from a standard array into a `numpy.array`.

```
angleDeg = np.array(angleDeg)
if not (angleDeg > 0).all():
    raise ValueError("angle must be between 0 and 90")
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm trying to make an exception, and I don't know how to fix it (I will post in original post)

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, you are trying to perform multiplication on a list, which does not support that operation. Change the line in f() from

```
angleRad = angleDeg*np.pi/180
```

to

```
angleRad = [deg*np.pi/180 for deg in angleDeg]
```

Answer (score 0):

your x is array which you pass x. I think you meant this:

```
x = [f(i) for i in x]
```

or this:

```
x = list(map(f,x))
```